# Visual Studio 2015 solution explorer manipulation: UIHierarchy vs IVsHierarchy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I am building a custom VS2015 Extension (VSIX package). My primary task is manipulations over the solution explorer like these:

1. Appending existing projects to solution
2. Removing projects from solution
3. Loading/unloading projects
4. Enumerating solution items, not only projects but also solution folders, unloaded projects, non-project items.

I have found some samples and most of them use one of the three common strategies:

1. `EnvDTE.Solution`, `EnvDTE.Project` and so on.
2. `EnvDTE.UIHierarchy` and the like.
3. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution` and `IVsHierarchy`

I can see that the first one is the most poor in terms of covered scenarios. What I cannot figure out is the difference between the last two. Which one should I dive in having my tasks in mind? What`s the concept behind them?

Comment: They are both interfaces implemented by the com solution object,

Answer (score -1):

They are both interfaces implemented by the com solution object. Check out the msdns to see the difference in methods.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.aspx

UIHierarchy is an interface to the tool **window** (any window with nodes, not just the solution explorer) that has a hierarchy in it and comes from the VSSDK whereas the IVs interfaces are coming in directly from interop and represent the actual items in the view.

For what you are saying the IVsSolution is the most direct interface. All IVsSolutions are also IVsHierarchy but any node in the solution explorer is a hierarchy but obviously not a solution.

Comment: You do not answer my question. What's the core difference between `UIHierarchy` and `IVsHierarchy`? What's the difference in the idea behind them?

Comment: expanded the answer

Comment: Do you mean that the `IVsHierarchy` is particularly for solution explorer and does not apply to other windows with nodes?

Comment: I believe it is for any 'nodes' not just solution explorer, you will want to confirm.

Comment: So both `UIHierarchy` and `IVsHierarch` are for any nodes. Whats the difference?

Comment: They come from different APIs. The IVs objects would never cast to UI objects and vica-versa, and have different methods, props everything. The UI objects are part of Visual Studio Automation SDK where the IVs objects are shell library interops.